# Replacing Drayton Boiler Control with something Home Assistant Compatible

Tags: electrical-panel, boiler, smart-switch

So I've got this Drayton controller on my oil-based boiler.

[image: Drayton Controller]

I've just pulled it off the wall to see what kind of connector it has, and its' got a weird connector with a whole bunch of pins on it, doesn't look like anything I'm familiar with (admittedly, I've only ever replaced thermostats, not whole controllers).

[image: Drayton Backplate]

So what do I need to look for to make sure that any smart replacement I buy is compatible with this? Is this standard wiring for boiler controllers or is it some weird protocol I need to be aware of?

Bonus points if you have any recommendations, but I really just want to know what I'm looking for.

(Note: those photos aren't mine, because the thing's quite hard to get to and I couldn't get a good photo, but I'm fairly sure they're representative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer was in-front of me the whole time...

The back of the boiler control actually has a wiring diagram on it.

All this controller does is switch power to heating and water loops.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

So I'd imagine any old controller will be fine.

Probably going to make my own to be honest... Make the most of my electronics engineering degree.